# how output using axios on new tab

Tags: reactjs, axios

I want to user click the button then the Axios output will show on the new tab (in about:blank or something like that)

axios:

```
click() {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });

    axios
    .get(
      `http://localhost:5000/model-list`
    )
    .then((res) => {
      this.setState({
       inferenceout: res.data , isLoading: false,
      })
     
      let newWin = window.open("about:blank", "res.data", "width=400,height=400");
      newWin.document.write(JSON.stringify(res.data))
    })
}
```

it currently returns the output JSON in new tab but I want the HTML script I wrote below will be in the new tab please help me

Comment: Can you please add that HTML here? Also, where are you referencing that HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
newWin.document.write(JSON.stringify(res.data))
```

You better use something like this embedding your JSON response, for example:

```
newWin.document.write(`<p>I am ${res.data.name} in new Window</p>`)
```

Comment: i get Object Object as a output bro

Comment: @KarthikeyanM You can embed those objects' properties inside HTML. If you still didn't get it please add the HTML and response object you're getting in the result.

Answer (score 0):

What are the HTML elements you want to pass to the new window?

You can use [string interpolation in JavaScript](https://dmitripavlutin.com/string-interpolation-in-javascript/) to pass the data with the HTML elements as follows,

```
newWin.document.write(`<html><p>Whatever HTML you want and the ${res.data.name} you wanted</p></html>`)
```

If you want the whole object you can do as follows,

```
newWin.document.write(`<html><p>Whatever HTML you want and the ${JSON.stringify(res)}</p></html>`)
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

At the first, read `axios` docs

[axios Docs](https://axios-http.com/docs/intro)

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const Component = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    const clickHandler = async (e) => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/model-list");
            
            document.write(response.data);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }

    return (
        <button 
            type="button"
            onClick={clickHandler}
        >
            Click Here
        </button
    );
};
```

Comment: Won't it overwrite the existing content of the page? And this won't solve his problem I think.

Comment: Do you want to overwrite the page or redirect to a new page?

Comment: What you're asking is already mentioned in the question.